# htaccess for url rewriting for two dynamic url for root

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I use following url rewrite from:

```
http://www.mapsopensource.com/m.php?url=asia-globe-map
```

to

```
http://www.mapsopensource.com/asia-globe-map.html
```

It rewrites quite well but when I combine this with another rule and try to rewrite the following the result is nothing:

```
http://www.mapsopensource.com/country.php?countryAlias=usa
```

to

```
http://www.mapsopensource.com/usa.html
```

Please guide me as to how I can combine both url rewrites in one htacess for two or more different dynamic urls.

My current code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /m\.php\?url=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /m.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /country\.php\?countryAlias=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /country.php?countryAlias=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: patterns must be more specific. `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+\-[a-z]+\-[a-z]+)\.html$ /m.php?url=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` `RewriteRule ^([a-z]{1,5})\.html$ /country.php?countryAlias=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: Asking same question again won't solve your problem.

Comment: @Deadooshka both are not working at same time either of one is working which in top

Comment: @anubhava but answer you gave was not relevant to me and not solving my issues, please be specifik with your answer, as i am not master in mod rewrite.

Comment: @RRPandey, how is the htaccess file meant to know if `/asia-globe-map.html` is meant to be silently rewritten to `m.php?url=asia-globe-map` or `country.php?countryAlias=asia-globe-map`?

Comment: @Howlin Its not recognizing, which one to be rewritten so the top one http://www.mapsopensource.com/m.php?url=asia-globe-map is rewritten to http://www.mapsopensource.com/asia-globe-map.html but http://www.mapsopensource.com/country.php?countryAlias=usa throws nothing but i am trying to be rewritten like http://www.mapsopensource.com/usa.html but no success.

Comment: @Howlin when i keep ".html" extension for http://www.mapsopensource.com/m.php?url=asia-globe-map and ".htm" or any other extension for (http://www.mapsopensource.com/country.php?countryAlias=usa) then both are parsing correctly but my requirement is ".html" for both url as its already indexed in search engine.

Comment: That is because it will always get rewritten to `m.php?url=usa`. Since the conditions for that is if the file/document doesn't exist then redirect it to `m.php?url=usa`

Comment: @Howlin ok, any other possibilities?

Comment: Change it so the country goes to `country/usa`?

Comment: yes that's better and i will redirect existing usa.html to country/usa . Thanks a lot